# Solve vectorial equations

Tags: vectors, vectorization

I'm trying to figure out a passage for reducing a vectorial equations ! for doing this somebody told me to use a program of symbolic calculation (matlab,maple, mathematical .. or python as well .. ) I never using symbolic calculation .. but i'm confiding in your knowledge for figure out how to solve my problem ! 
here the equation :

$$ \mathbf{v}_l + \mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{v}_l = \mathbf{B} $$

where

$$ \mathbf{A} = \frac{D}{D_0}\mathbf{s'}, $$ 
$$ \mathbf{B} = \frac{\rho_s k}{D_0}(\mathbf{V_s+v_s}) -\frac{D_t}{D_0}\mathbf{v_n}+\frac{D}{D_0}\mathbf{s'}\times \mathbf{v_n}+\frac{\chi}{D_0}\mathbf{s'} $$
where $\chi $ is a generic constant. 
The solution of the first equations is:
$$\mathbf{v}_l = \frac{1}{(1+A^2)}[\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B} + (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}   ) \mathbf{A} ] $$

how this solution comes from ??? I found it in the paper [paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vqXs5kaKhLGY0H73R5mf1Ds5IFga1WXX/view?usp=sharing) (eq 14) 
I'm wait for your precious Help !! thanks in advance

I add the pdf on the web

Comment: paper is behind a paywall. (or at least it is to me) so would it be possible to get a bit more information?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

I suppose that your vectors are in $3$D space. In tis case , if $\mathbf A=(A_x,A_y,A_z)^T$, we can represent the cross product as a matrix operation as:
$$
\mathbf A \times \mathbf v_l=\mathbf A_{[\times]}\mathbf v_l=\begin{pmatrix}
0&-A_z&A_y\\
A_z&0&-A_x\\
-A_y&A_x&0
\end{pmatrix} \mathbf v_l
$$
So your equation becomes:
$$
\left(\mathbf I+ \mathbf A_{[\times]}\right)\mathbf v_l=\mathbf B
$$

and the solution is:
$$
\mathbf v_l=\left(\mathbf I+ \mathbf A_{[\times]}\right)^{-1} \mathbf B
$$
If you calculate  the inverse matrix
$$
\left(\mathbf I+ \mathbf A_{[\times]}\right)^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-A_z&A_y\\
A_z&1&-A_x\\
-A_y&A_x&1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$
I think that you can find the result.

---

Using WolframAlpha I found:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-A_z&A_y\\
A_z&1&-A_x\\
-A_y&A_x&1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=
\frac{1}{A_x^2+A_y^2+A_z^2+1}
\begin{pmatrix}
1+A_x^2&A_xA_y+A_z&A_xA_z-A_y\\
A_xA_y-A_z&1+A_y^2&A_x+A_yA_z\\
A_y+A_xA_z&A_yA_z-A_x&1+A_z^2\\
\end{pmatrix}=
$$

$$=\frac{1}{1+A^2}\left[
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
0&A_z&-A_y\\
-A_z&0&A_x\\
A_y&-A_x&0\\
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
A_x^2&A_xA_y&A_xA_z\\
A_xA_y&A_y^2&A_yA_z\\
A_xA_z&A_yA_z&A_z^2\\
\end{pmatrix}
\right]
$$

And multiplying by $\mathbf B=(B_x,B_y,B_z)^T$ you can find the result in a form that is the same as in OP. The only difference is the factor $\frac{1}{1+A^2}$. Maybe a sign typo  in the question or in the solution?

Comment: sorry In which way ?? i calculate it but i didn't got the solutions

Comment: I added to my answer. Maybe that there is a sign typo in OP?

Comment: your right !!! it's exact $$\frac{1}{(1+A^2)} $$ could you explain me how i have to multiply for B ?

Comment: I don't understand where the $$\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B} $$ come from ...

Comment: could somebody help me with the last passage ? I don't have wolframe or maple here in my laptop ... could you help me in this way ?

Comment: is this correct ?$$\mathbf{v}_l=
\frac{1}{1+A^2}\left[
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} B_x\\B_y\\B_z\\ \end{pmatrix}  %\mathbf{B}
}_{\normalsize \mathbf{B}}
+
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0&A_z&-A_y\\
-A_z&0&A_x\\
A_y&-A_x&0\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} B_x\\B_y\\B_z\\ \end{pmatrix} %\mathbf{B} 
}_{- \mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B}}
+
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
A_x^2&A_xA_y&A_xA_z\\
A_xA_y&A_y^2&A_yA_z\\
A_xA_z&A_yA_z&A_z^2\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} B_x\\B_y\\B_z\\ \end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{(A \cdot B)A}}
\right]$$

Comment: Yes, it is corrrect !

Answer (score 0):

I'll try this two different ways.

---

First, let's continue the solution by Emilio Novati.
There is some matrix multiplication involved here, so let's do it
step by step.

First we multiply by $\mathbf B$ on the right in order to get the
desired vector $\mathbf v_l$:

$$\mathbf v_l=\frac 1{1+A^2}\left[ \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix}0&A_z&-A_y\\-A_z&0&A_x\\A_y&-A_x&0\end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix}A_x^2&A_xA_y&A_xA_z\\A_xA_y&A_y^2&A_yA_z\\A_xA_z&A_yA_z&A_z^2\end{pmatrix}\right]\mathbf B.$$

Matrix multiplication distributes over matrix addition, so we have
$$\mathbf v_l =
\frac 1{1+A^2}\left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\mathbf B + \begin{pmatrix}0&A_z&-A_y\\-A_z&0&A_x\\A_y&-A_x&0\end{pmatrix} \mathbf B + 
\begin{pmatrix}A_x^2&A_xA_y&A_xA_z\\A_xA_y&A_y^2&A_yA_z\\A_xA_z&A_yA_z&A_z^2\end{pmatrix}\mathbf B
\right].$$

Now let's take the three terms inside the brackets one at a time,
denoting the three components of $\mathbf B$ like this:
$$ \mathbf B = \begin{pmatrix}B_x\\B_y\\B_z\end{pmatrix}.$$

So now we have some matrix multiplications. Matrix multiplication 
[is defined on Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMultiplication.html) among many other places;
[Purplemath has a nice animation of the process](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/mtrxmult.htm).
In the particular formula above, every matrix multiplication is
a $3\times3$ matrix by a $3\times1$ matrix, and the rule is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}m_{11}&m_{12}&m_{13}\\m_{21}&m_{22}&m_{23}\\m_{31}&m_{32}&m_{33}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}m_{11}v_1+m_{12}v_2+m_{13}v_3\\
m_{21}v_1+m_{22}v_2+m_{23}v_3\\
m_{31}v_1+m_{32}v_2+m_{33}v_3\end{pmatrix}
$$

First we have multiplication by an identity matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}B_x\\B_y\\B_z\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}B_x\\B_y\\B_z\end{pmatrix} = \mathbf B.$$

For the next term, let's write
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&A_z&-A_y\\-A_z&0&A_x\\A_y&-A_x&0\end{pmatrix}
= -\begin{pmatrix}0&-A_z&A_y\\A_z&0&-A_x\\-A_y&A_x&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

So now we just have to confirm that
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&-A_z&A_y\\A_z&0&-A_x\\-A_y&A_x&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}B_x\\B_y\\B_z\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}A_yB_z-A_zB_y\\A_zB_x-A_xB_z\\A_xB_y-A_yB_x\end{pmatrix}
= \mathbf A \times \mathbf B,$$
confirming that multiplication by the matrix $\mathbf A_{[\times]}$
does indeed perform a cross product as stated by Emilio Novarti.

Finally we look at the third term:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}A_x^2&A_xA_y&A_xA_z\\A_xA_y&A_y^2&A_yA_z\\A_xA_z&A_yA_z&A_z^2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}B_x\\B_y\\B_z\end{pmatrix} &=
\begin{pmatrix}A_x^2B_x+A_xA_yB_y+A_xA_zB_z\\A_xA_yB_x+A_y^2B_y+A_yA_zB_z\\A_xA_zB_x+A_yA_zB_y+A_z^2B_z\end{pmatrix} \\
&= (A_xB_x+A_yB_y+A_zB_z) \begin{pmatrix}A_x\\A_y\\A_z\end{pmatrix} \\
&= (\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \mathbf A.
\end{align}

---

For the second way,
we take the formula
$$\frac1{1+A^2}[\mathbf B - \mathbf A\times\mathbf B  + (\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \mathbf A],$$
which is proposed as the value of $\mathbf{v}_l,$
and try plugging it into the formula
$$ \mathbf{v}_l + \mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{v}_l$$
to see if we actually come up with the result $\mathbf{B}$ as desired.
First let's work on the term $\mathbf A\times\mathbf v_l.$ 
Using various rules of vector arithmetic, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbf A\times\mathbf v_l &=
\mathbf A\times\left[\frac1{1+A^2}[\mathbf B - \mathbf A\times\mathbf B + (\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \mathbf A]\right] \\
 &= \frac1{1+A^2}[\mathbf A\times\mathbf B - \mathbf A\times(\mathbf A\times\mathbf B) + \mathbf A\times(\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \mathbf A] \\
 &= \frac1{1+A^2}[\mathbf A\times\mathbf B - \mathbf A\times(\mathbf A\times\mathbf B)],
\end{align}
because
$$
\mathbf A\times(\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \times\mathbf A
= (\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) [\mathbf A\times\mathbf A] = \mathbf 0.
$$
Therefore the proposed substitution for $\mathbf v_l$ says that
\begin{align}
\mathbf v_l + \mathbf A \times \mathbf v_l
&= \frac1{1+A^2}[\mathbf B - \mathbf A\times\mathbf B  + (\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \mathbf A] 
+ \frac1{1+A^2}[\mathbf A\times\mathbf B - \mathbf A\times(\mathbf A\times\mathbf B)] \\
&= \frac1{1+A^2}[\mathbf B + (\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \mathbf A
     - \mathbf A\times(\mathbf A\times\mathbf B)].
\end{align}

Next, let's see how the vectors $(\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \mathbf A$ and $\mathbf A\times(\mathbf A\times\mathbf B)$ relate to the plane containing $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B.$
Defining $A = \|\mathbf A\|$ and $B = \|\mathbf B\|,$
if $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$
then $\mathbf A\times\mathbf B$ is a vector of length
$AB\sin\theta$ perpendicular to the plane
containing $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B.$
But $\mathbf A\times(\mathbf A\times\mathbf B)$ is perpendicular to
$\mathbf A\times\mathbf B,$ so it's in the plane
containing $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B,$
and it's also perpendicular to $\mathbf A.$
By a couple of applications of the right-hand rule for the cross product,
we find that $\mathbf A\times(\mathbf A\times\mathbf B)$ is on the side of
$\mathbf A$ opposite from $\mathbf B,$
so $-\mathbf A\times(\mathbf A\times\mathbf B)$ is on the same side
as $\mathbf B$ and makes an angle $\frac\pi2 - \theta$ with $\mathbf B.$
Moreover, its length is 
$$A(AB\sin\theta)\sin\frac\pi2
= A^2B\sin\theta$$

Meanwhile, $\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B = AB\cos\theta,$ so
$(\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \mathbf A$ is a vector
of length $A^2B\cos\theta$ parallel to $\mathbf A.$
So now we have two perpendicular vectors, one of length
$A^2B\cos\theta$ parallel to $\mathbf A$ and the other of length 
$A^2B\sin\theta$ perpendicular to $\mathbf A.$
The vector sum of these vectors is a vector of length
$A^2B$ at an angle $\theta$ from $\mathbf A$;
in fact it is exactly in the same direction as $\mathbf B,$
and it is the vector $A^2 \mathbf B.$ That is,
$$ (\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \mathbf A
     - \mathbf A\times(\mathbf A\times\mathbf B) = A^2 \mathbf B.$$

So now we have
$$ \mathbf{v}_l + \mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{v}_l
= \frac1{1+A^2}[\mathbf B + A^2 \mathbf B] = \mathbf B,
$$
showing that 
$$\mathbf{v}_l = \frac1{1+A^2}[\mathbf B - \mathbf A\times\mathbf B  + (\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B) \mathbf A]$$
is indeed a solution of that equation.